# If pair of tangents to a circle in the first quadrant is $6x^2-5xy+y^2=0$ and if one point of contact is $(1,2)$, find the radius.

Tags: conic-sections

The tangents are $2x-y=0$ and $3x-y=0$. Let the radius be $r$ and centre be $(h,k)$

$$r=\frac{|3h-k|}{\sqrt {10}}$$
$$r=\frac{|2h-k|}{\sqrt 5}$$
$$(h-1)^2+(k-2)^2=r^2$$

I invested a considerable amount of effort in solving this equations, but to no result. My method was to square all terms to avoid the modulus, but that complicated things adding the $hk$ term. This also led me to believe that there must be a better way to solve this. Can I know how this problem must be approached?

Comment: The radius is the distance from $(1,2)$ to the appropriate angle bisector.

Comment: @amd angle bisector of what though

Comment: Of the two tangents, of course. The centers of all of the circles to which they are mutually tangent lie on the two bisectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perpendicular to $y=2x$ throught $(1,2)$ is:
$$y=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}$$
The line bisector of the two lines $y=2x$ and $y=3x$ is:
$$y=(\sqrt2+1)x$$
The other bisector line is:
$$y=(\sqrt2-1)x$$
but in this case the circunference wouldn't be tangent to either $y=2x$ and $y=3x$ lines.

Now, we have to inresect these two lines, or:
$$(\sqrt2+1)x=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2} \leftrightarrow x=5(3-2\sqrt2) \land y=-5+5\sqrt2$$
From this we can compute:
$$r=\sqrt{(14-10\sqrt2)^2+(-7+5\sqrt2)^2}=\sqrt{(5\sqrt{10}-7\sqrt5)^2}=5\sqrt{10}-7\sqrt5$$

Note that we pass from $(14-10\sqrt2)^2+(-7+5\sqrt2)^2$ to $(5\sqrt{10}-7\sqrt5)^2$, simply calculating the first sum and then solve for $a,b$ this system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a^2+b^2=495
\\ 2ab=-350\sqrt2
\end{matrix}\right.$$
And the solutions are:
$$a=\pm5\sqrt{10} \land y=\mp7\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: Actually, I got $y=5(\sqrt 2-1)$

Comment: @Aditya: also I.

Comment: Okay, so solving with that, I get $r=5\sqrt {12-8\sqrt 2}$. But $r$ is of the form $\sqrt {\alpha}-\sqrt {\beta}$, where $\alpha-\beta=5$

Comment: @Aditya: here my solution.

Comment: It might be good to mention why you chose the particular bisector of the two that you did.

Comment: I didn’t understand the part where you factorized them. What are $a$ and $b$ supposed to represent

Comment: @Aditya: We suppose $(14-10\sqrt2)^2+(-7+5\sqrt2)^2$ can be represented as: $$(a+b)^2$$so we have: 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a^2+b^2=495
\\ 2ab=-350\sqrt2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

The radius is equal to the distance from $(1,2)$ to the appropriate angle bisector of the two tangent lines. These bisectors are $${2x-y\over\sqrt5}=\pm{3x-y\over\sqrt{10}}.$$ Choose the one for which the circle will be in the first quadrant.

Comment: Solving it, I got the radius as $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt {20+14\sqrt 2}}$, and upon simplification ended up being $\frac{\sqrt{10-7\sqrt 2}}{2}$, but the answer is in the form of $\sqrt {\alpha}+\sqrt {\beta}$

Comment: @Aditya If you want to reverse-engineer the given solution, you’ll have to try to guess how $\alpha$ and $\beta$ relate to the values that you have. Perhaps you’re not meant to factor the original equation and work directly with that somehow. I’m not even going to hazard a guess without knowing $\alpha$ and $\beta$, though.

Comment: I don’t know what alpha and beta are, I just know their difference. That’s the answer